# "unhashable type: dict" error checking if key is present in a dictionary?

Tags: python, typeerror

I've got a question concerning this code line:

```
if key in self.__class__.__dict__:
```

This leads to an "unhashable type: 'dict'" error but I don't know why.
I don't try to use a dictonary as key in another dictonary (or do I implicitly.. somehow?). When I do

```
print self.__class__.__dict__
```

I get a perfectly fine looking dictonary.

Comment: What is the type of `key`? Try `{} in {}`, it gives the same error. I'm guessing `key` is a dictionary.

Comment: `key` is whether a `dict` or contains a `dict` at some level (e.g. `(1, (2, {}))`). The problem is in it, not in `self.__class__.__dict__`. Try to `print repr(key)` and include the output into the question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the complete Tradeback.

Comment: You are totally right. I made a mistake before so key could become a dict. Thank you.